# Consulta em banco de dados com java

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados, query

Vou fazer uma comparação com o meu problema utilizando uma funcionalidade do banco de dados e JQuery do html.

Com o JQuery temos a possibilidade de visitar o banco de dados e trazer os dados para o frontend no HTML, e isso pode ser feito constantemente sem influenciar na interface do usuário(HTML) ou que tudo pare até que a consulta seja realizada.

O meu problema no java é que tenho uma JTable e os dados dela são pegos num banco de dados e a tabela consultada esta em constante mudança, com novos dados sendo inseridos e eu preciso que a JTable aconpanhe essas mudanças.

Existe alguma maneira ou algo que possibilite isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se entendi corretamente qual a sua dúvida, mas caso seja simplesmente atualizar os dados de uma JTable, é só fazer uma nova consulta no banco de dados e passar o resultado para JTable. Como exemplo tenho o trecho de código de um projeto meu que utiliza o padrão MVC.

```
//método para listar os alunos que atuam como monitores de disciplinas
public void listar(String str){
    //instancio um objeto que me permita fazer consulta no banco de dados
    MonitorDAO dao = new MonitorDAO();
    //realizo a consulta e coloco o resultado num ArrayList
    monitores = dao.consultaMonitores(str);
    //seto para a JTable um novo TableModel que vai receber o resultado da consulta anterior
    tela.getTabela().setModel(new MonitorTableModel(monitores));
}
```

Tendo este método, eu o chamo sempre que for necessário atualizar os dados da JTable.